# Add a value to an existing value

Tags: javascript

I want to add a number to another number that is defined by the user in a text box. The number that is added is determined by a string or code typed into a separate text box, controlled by an event handler.

Scenario
User enters a value of `"70"` into text box 1. User then types code `"Valley"` into text box 2 which should automatically add `"28"` to `"70"` in text box 1 and display the new value `"98"` in text box 1.

Is this possible ? If so what is the best way of approaching it. I have a basic understanding of JavaScript. Below is the start I have made, pretty pathetic I know. Any help is greatly appreciated because I am stumped as to where to go from here.

```
var TrackingCode = document.getElementById("textbox_2").value;
var textDay = "";
if (TrackingCode == "VALLEY") {
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var TrackingCode = document.getElementById("textbox_2").value;
var box1 = document.getElementById("textbox_1");
if (TrackingCode == "VALLEY") {
    box1.value = Number(box1.value) + 28;
}
```

Note the `Number` cast is required, or you'll get `7028`.

Comment: `box1.value = +box1.value + 28;`

Comment: Perfect, thank you. If I wanted to expand on that though, and have that value added dependant on a value selected from a drop down list, for example, same scenario as original post, except the user selects a value between 1 and 10 from a list, this is then multiplied by 28 and added to textbox1, how would I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can store all your codes in an object as a kind of dictionary:

```
var codes = {
    "VALLEY": 28,
    "FIELD" : 42,
    "MOUNTAIN" : 7,
    "STREAM" : 99,
    "PLATEAU" : 18
};
```

Then get the values and add them up like this:

```
var firstNumber = parseFloat(document.getElementById("textbox_1").value);
var trackingCode = document.getElementById("textbox_2").value;
if (isFinite(firstNumber) && trackingCode in codes)
{
    var codeValue = codes[trackingCode];
    var sum = firstNumber + codeValue;
}
```

Of course, you could also just use a `<select>` list box.

```
<select id="trackingCodeListBox">
    <option value="28">VALLEY</option>
    <option value="42">FIELD</option>
    <option value="7">MOUNTAIN</option>
    <option value="99">STREAM</option>
    <option value="18">PLATEAU</option>
</select>
```

Then you would just get the value of the the selected item:

```
var listBox = document.getElementById("trackingCodeListBox");
var selectedCode = listBox.options[listBox.selectedIndex].value;
var trackingCode = parseFloat(selectedCode);  // or parseInt() if appropriate;
```

Comment: Any reason as to why firstNumber is float and not say an integer.

Comment: And to implement your solution using a select list box gilly? Im really not trying to be a leech, I'm a designer that really needs more development experience haha. I really appreciate the help

Comment: @Piyush - The question didn't say anything about the numbers only being integers.  I don't want to make any assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.

```
function execute()
{
    var TrackingCode = document.getElementById("tracking_code").value;
    var box1 = document.getElementById("packageCostA");
    var num = document.getElementById("adults_nr").value;
    if (TrackingCode == "VALLEY") {
        packageCostA.value = Number(packageCostA.value) + 28*adults_nr.value;
    }
}
```

That's what I ended up with, it now works how I want it to.